# How to read AAPL data using pandas_datareader

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read Apple stock data using pandas_datareader, but I'm getting error

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime
start = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2018, 1,1)

df= web.get_data_yahoo(['AAPL'],start=start,end=end)
```

Error:

```
'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: Thnx bro, it worked